# Rails why routing error? No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller, routes

i dont understand

in routes.rb i have write

```
   match  'promotions/:id/purchase' => 'promotions#purchase', :as => :purchase_promo
```

in the promotions_controller.rb i have add:

```
    def purchase
    @promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # purchase.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @promotion }
    end
    end
```

and have create in the view promotions a file purchase.erb.html

```
   <div data-role="page" id="acquisto">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
    <h1>Purchase?</h1>
   </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
    <h4>This promo costs <%= @promotion.price  %> .</h4>
    <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.</p>
     <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Purchase       album</a>
     <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back">No thanks</a>

     </div>

     </div><!-- /page -->
```

and in a other page write

```
    <%= link_to 'Buy Promo',:purchase_promo ,'data-rel'=>'dialog',' data-transition'=>'slideup' %>
```

what is wrong?

**i get routing error**

No route matches {:controller=>"promotions", :action=>"purchase"}

Comment: Does your `routes.rb` have a `resources :promotions` line in it?

Comment: yes i already have resources :promotions in routes.rb

Comment: I think it should be `<%= link_to 'Buy Promo', purchase_promo_path, ...`

Comment: i write purchase_promo_patch but always No route matches {:controller=>"promotions", :action=>"purchase"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route you've created requires an ID.  To link to it, use:

```
link_to 'Buy Promo', purchase_promo_path(some_id)
```

It's not immediate clear to me what the proper ID source is, but based on the code you've provided, you probably want:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy Promo', purchase_promo_path(@promotion) ,'data-rel'=>'dialog',' data-transition'=>'slideup' %>
```

You can also construct a route like this via something like:

```
resources :promotions do
  member do
    post :purchase
  end
end
```

That will create normal collection-level and member-level routes (`index`, `show`, etc.), and also create an additional member-level route for `purchase`, using the `POST` method (you probably want that for initiating a purchase, to be RESTful).  In both cases, you'll need to provide the ID and use `_path` helpers to get the URL.